# Bad Archive Mirror when using ethernet

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I have a Ubuntu minimal install USB. But, my computer depends on a wireless USB.

Is there anyway to either

- A) Get Ubuntu setup to recognize my wireless USB or
- B) Hook up to ethernet and than successfully install the archive mirror?

Help would be appreciated.

Also, for you guys that say "Go the Ethernet way", I already tried, and it's telling me on all archive mirrors `Bad Archive Mirror`

Comment: you shouldn't be having 'bad archive mirror' so are you using a supported version (14.04, 16.04, 17.10)?

Comment: I am using 17.10